# How to properly free a dynamically allocated array in C

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic

I am trying to write a set of functions that will support a dynamically allocated array where a struct contains the array and other metadata.  The goal is to return the function to the user, and the struct information can be called from a function.  The code seems to work just fine until I get to the function to free the memory from heap.  For reasons I do not understand, the code fails with a segmentation fault, which would indicate that the variable `vec` in the `free_vector` function is not pointing to the correct address.  However, I have verified with print statements that it is pointing to the correct address.  I am hoping someone can help me understand why the `free_vector` function is not working, specifically the `free` command.  My code and implementation is shown below.

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t allocated_length;
    size_t active_length;
    size_t num_bytes;
    char *vector;
} Vector;

void *init_vector(size_t num_indices, size_t num_bytes) {
    // Allocate memory for Vector struct
    Vector *vec = malloc(sizeof(*vec));
    vec->active_length = 0;
    vec->num_bytes = num_bytes;

    // Allocate heap memory for vector
    void *ptr = malloc(num_bytes * num_indices);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("WARNING: Unable to allocate memory, exiting!\n");
        return &vec->vector;
    }
    vec->allocated_length = num_indices;
    vec->vector = ptr;
    return &vec->vector;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int push_vector(void *vec, void *elements, size_t num_indices) {
    Vector *a = get_vector_data(vec);
    if(a->active_length + num_indices > a->allocated_length) {
        printf("TRUE\n");
        size_t size = (a->allocated_length + num_indices) * 2;
        void *ptr = realloc(a->vector, size * a->num_bytes);
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            printf("WARNING: Unable to allocate memory, exiting!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        a->vector = ptr;
        a->allocated_length = size;
    }
    memcpy((char *)vec + a->active_length * a->num_bytes, elements,
            num_indices * a->num_bytes);
    a->active_length += num_indices;
    return 1;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Vector *get_vector_data(void *vec) {
    // - The Vector struct has three size_t variables that proceed the vector
    //   variable.  These variables consume 24 bytes of daya.  THe code below
    //   points backwards in memory by 24 bytes to the beginning of the Struct.
    char *a = (char *)vec - 24;
    return (Vector *)a;
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void free_vector(void *vec) {
    // Free all Vector struct elements
    Vector *a = get_vector_data(vec);
    // - This print statement shows that the variable is pointing to the
    //   correct data.
    printf("%d\n" ((int *)vec)[2]);
    // The function fails on the next line and I do not know why
    free(a->vector);
    a->vector = NULL;
    a->allocated_length = 0;
    a->active_length = 0;
    a->num_bytes = 0;
}

int main() {
    int *a = init_vector(3, sizeof(int));
    int b[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    push_vector(a, b, 3);
    // The code begins to fails here
    free_vector(a);
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `&vec->vector` instead of `vec->vector`?

Comment: What's going on here: `char *a = (char *)vec - 24;`? You shouldn't hard-code sizes, use the `offsetof` macro.

Comment: Your code example seems to be incomplete, missing at least a few `#include`s.

Comment: All your uses of `void*` are preventing the compiler from giving you warnings about all the mismatched pointer types.

Comment: Why don't you just use `return vec;` and then use this structure throughout your code?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thats a very productive comment, can you give some examples?

Comment: @Barmar Thats a great question! Truth be told I am trying to reproduce a code example that was demonstrated on youtube with the github page attached.  I like the user interface, but despite the coder showing a working example on youtube, the code on his github page does not compile with any compiler I can find, and th egithub page seems incoherent.  https://github.com/Mashpoe/c-vector . I am trying to reverse code the example in a way that actually compiles while preserving the intent, and was wondering the same thing and thought maybe I was missing something.

Comment: @Barmar Why is hard coding the 24 bad?  I have no intention of adding variables to the Struct and I also do not intend to change their type.  If I pass a pointer to the beginning of the vector, then it should always be 24 bytes in memory behind it.

Comment: @Jon You should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes the definition of the structure. Hard coding offsets is generally bad because of the relationship between [alignment & padding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object), and the fact that the bit width of types depends on the environment.

Comment: @Oka That was accidental, I thought I had included the Struct.  I have updated the question to include that information.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code 24 because it assumes a specific structure layout and data sizes. C has `sizeof` and `offsetof` so that you don't have to make assumptions about these implementation-dependent values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program suffers from [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

The return value from `init_vector` is of type `char **`, a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char*,

```
return &vec->vector;
```

converted to `void *`.

In `main`, this value is converted to an `int *`

```
int *a = init_vector(3, sizeof(int));
```

This value is then converted back into a `void *` when passed to `push_vector`.

In `push_vector`, this value is cast to a `char *` in order to perform pointer arithmetic

```
memcpy((char *)vec + a->active_length * a->num_bytes, elements,
            num_indices * a->num_bytes);
```

where this operation overwrites the original pointer returned by `malloc` contained in the `vector` member.

On my system, this attempts to write 12 bytes (three `int`) to memory starting with the position of the `vector` member in the `Vector` structure.

```
Vector *vec
|                    &vec->vector
|                    |      
v                    v      
+------+------+------+------+-----+
|size_t|size_t|size_t|char *|?????|
+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

This overflows, as `sizeof (char *)` is `8` on my system.

This is the wrong place to write data. The correct place to write data is `*(char **) vec` - or just `a->vector`.

If the write does not crash the program directly ([UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)), this surely results in `free` being passed a pointer value that was not returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, or the pointer value `NULL`.

---

Aside: In `free_vector`, this value is also cast to an `int *`

```
printf("%d\n", ((int *)vec)[2]); /* added a missing semi-colon. */
```

---

Additionally, it is unclear if `free_vector` should free the original allocation, or just the `vector` member. You do go to lengths to zero-out the structure here.

Still, as is, you have a memory leak - albeit a small one.

```
void free_vector(void *vec) {
    Vector *a = get_vector_data(vec);
    /* ... */
    free(a); /* This has to happen at some point. */
}
```

Note, you should be using [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) to calculate the position of members within a structure. A static offset of `24` assumes two thing that may **not** hold true:

- `sizeof (size_t)` is always `8` (actual minimum `sizeof (size_t)` is `2`), and
- the structure contains no [padding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) to satisfy alignment (this seems likely given the form, but not strictly true).

---

The [source](https://github.com/Mashpoe/c-vector) you linked in the comments uses a [flexible array member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct), not a pointer member, meaning the entirety of the data (allocation sizes and the vector) is stored in contiguous memory. That is why the `&` operator yields a valid location to copy data to in this implementation.

(*Aside: the linked implementation appears to be broken by effectively using `sizeof` to get the base of the container structure from a pointer to the flexible array member (e.g., `&((vector_container *) pointer_to_flexible_member)[-1]`), which does not take into account the possibility of trailing padding, which would result in a larger offset than expected.*)

Comment: There is a bit to unpack here that may take me a bit, but lets start with the `(char *)vec` point.  If I removed the `free_vector` from my main code, and compile as well as run the software as written, it works.  if I put the `printf("%d\n", a[i])` in a for loop, it correctly prints out the integer values 1, 2, 3, as expected, which indicates they were written to the correct spaces in memory.  If I re-write that section with `*(char **)vec` the way you recommend it prints gibberish values.  I trust your assessment to be correct, but I am trying to reconcile the results.

Comment: Remember that *"it works"* and *"it appears to work"* are indistinguishable once UB is invoked - any result is valid, including what appears to be the expected one, but the program is defunct. `int *a = init_vector(...)` is *wrong*, if that wasn't clear. Accessing `int` objects via this pointer is incorrect. Fixing the `memcpy` code, but not fixing this issue means reading `int`-sized slices of a  `char *` pointer (and likely some memory beyond). Just because you wrote values to memory, and read back from memory those same values, does not mean it was the correct memory to use.

Comment: Aside: strictly speaking I did not *recommend* anything, `*(char **) vec` **is** the address of the allocation. If I had to recommend something, it would be to abandon this approach once you understand why it is troublesome, as there is unlikely to be a worthwhile solution that exposes a user friendly API (direct access to the vector, while maintaining a *"fat pointer"*, is not really possible with a pointer member). As explained, there is a reason the implementation you linked uses a flexible array member.

Comment: I already have a working version that requires passing the struct to the push function, where the flexible member must be cast when used, as apposed to this implementation.  I am more interested at this point in using this example as a learning opportunity.  For instance I did not even know that `offsetof` was even an existing macro until I posted this question.

Comment: After a few hours of looking over my solution and the original approach, I think I see the problems with both.  Thank you!